# How to avoid the class rewritten in multi thread processing?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, parallel-processing

I wrote this code in order to use parallel processing:

```
var charge = new Charge[Job.Jobs.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < Job.Jobs.Length; i++)
{
    charge[i] = new Charge
    {
        ID = Convert.ToInt64(Job.Jobs[i].Parameters),
        Job = new SystemJob { ID = Job.Jobs[i].ID, Type = Job.Type },
    };
    var status = charge[i].GetSubscribeInformation();
    if (status == false)
        continue;

    Task.Run(() => charge[i].Subscribe());
    //before task runs, the i value changes and causes error.
}
```

The problem is before `Task.Run(() => charge[i].Subscribe());` execution the `i` value changes and causes error. How can I avoid this?
I can wait until after `Task.Run()` but it doesn't seem like a good idea. What choices do I have?

Comment: Have you considered using `Parallel.ForEach` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i never heard of. would you please explain little bit?

Comment: See the link in my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the iterated index into a closure:

```
Task.Run(() => charge[i].Subscribe());
```

You have to copy it to the local value:

```
var localI = i;
Task.Run(() => charge[localI].Subscribe());
```

Also you can get rid from the Task creation by using `Parallel` class, as @Bauss suggested (I assume here that you have instantiated your array `charge` variable) (code updated for `return` usage):

```
Parallel.ForEach(charge, (c) => 
{
    var status = c.GetSubscribeInformation();
    if (!status)
    {
        return;
    }
    c.Subscribe();
    // some other code here
});
```

Also you can remove the check for boolean condition:

```
if (status == false)
```

is the same as:

```
if (!status)
```

Comment: smart. Thanks men. should i use Parallel.for instead?

Comment: @Dan added some sample code for `Parallel.Foreach`, `Parallel.For` is quite the same in use.

Comment: thank you so much. why i cant use the continue? its kind of important to me.

Comment: this code is running as a separate method, so you should use `return`, not continue. I've updated the code